# Why sometimes the bars with bar or hist have no border?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, histogram

I noticed that sometimes, when I plot the bars using the functions bar() or hist(), the bars plotted have no border. They are a little bit less nice to see, and I would prefer the border or a little bit of space between them.
The figure shows what I got now, plotting three different datasets. The third graph is zoomed in order to show the lack of space between bars. 
[image]

I get there this has something to do with the 'histc' parameters in bar function. Without the histc parameters the bars have some space between each others, but then the bar will be centered on the edges values, whereas I want the edges values to be, well, EDGES of each bar.

This is (the relevant part of) the code I used:

```
 [...]
 if edges==0
        %these following lines are used to take the min and max of the three dataset
        maxx=max(cellfun(@max, reshape(data,1,size(data,1)*size(data,2))));
        minn=min(cellfun(@min, reshape(data,1,size(data,1)*size(data,2))));
        edges=minn:binW:maxx+binW;
    end
    [...]
     y{k}=histc(data{r,c}, edges);
    bar(edges,y{k} , 'histc');
    [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you change the color of your bar plots you'll see that there actually is a border it just doesn't show up very well. You can also change the width of the bars so that they are more distinct.

```
% something to plot
data = 100*rand(1000,1);
edges = 1:100;

hData = histc(data,edges);

figure
subplot(2,1,1)
h1 = bar(edges,hData,'histc');
% change colors
set(h1,'FaceColor','m')
set(h1,'EdgeColor','b')

% Change width
subplot(2,1,2)
h1 = bar(edges,hData,0.4,'histc');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `EdgeColor` and `LineWidth` properties of the [Barseries](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/barseriesproperties.html#f18-655859) object control the bar outlines. Try using the code and playing with the red, green, blue, and width values to get a better result.

```
    red = 1;
    green = 1;
    blue = 1;
    width = 3;
    h = bar(edges,y{k} , 'histc');
    set(h,'EdgeColor',[red green blue],'LineWidth',width);
```